# Is it possible to un-install MS Office 2007 to 'un-use' an activation?

Tags: microsoft-office

I know that there is a limit of 5 activations for the MS Office 2007 license.  Over the years the computer it's been installed on has gone through a few wipes/reinstalls.  I know that you can call MS and do a telephone activation (and hope they are okay with the extra install), but is there a way to remove the software from the computer pre-emptively to release one of those activations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to deactivate the software.

Go to Control Panel> installed programs > Scroll through the list of installed programs. Locate and highlight the "Microsoft Office 2007" tab. The Microsoft Office 2007 Activation program will be listed below the Office 2007 program suite. Click on the "Uninstall" action at the top of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling it should deactivate the liscense. It did for ms office 2003 so I would think it it would still work. If not then just google how to deqctivate ms office liscense.